# can $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^n;\mathbb{Z})$ be the cohomology of some Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(\pi,1)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Recently I came across the following question:
can $H^*(\mathbb{C}P^n;\mathbb{Z})$ be the integral cohomology ring of some Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(\pi,1)$?
I guess (without strong evidences) that the answer is negative. If so, how to prove it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up the (incredible) Kan-Thurston theorem.

Comment: Oh, I see Andy Putman already wrote that a minute earlier.

Answer (score 21):

The Kan-Thurston theorem says that every path-connected space is homology equivalent to an Eilenberg-MacLane space, so the answer is "yes".  See

Daniel Kan and William Thurston, [Every connected space has the homology of a K(π,1)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(76)90040-9), Topology Vol. 15. pp. 253–258, 1976.